# Are there nested Matrixes in "The Matrix: Resurrections"?

Tags: the-matrix

In *The Matrix Reloaded* and *The Matrix Revolutions* there are references to the nested Matrices, in other words "Matrix inside Matrix".

Are there any references of such "nesting" in *The Matrix Resurrections*?

Comment: You are right, may be it is not that common: "Matrixes is the modern English version and matrices is the plural form from the Latin word"

Comment: Maybe "Matrices"? If they're nested, then "Matreshki"?

Comment: I use "matrices" all the time, and that form is very common mathematics.  However, the standard form could be different with the in-universe proper noun "Matrix."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In a word, *maybe*. At the start of *The Matrix Resurrection*, Neo is stuck inside the latest version of the Matrix. In his spare time he's used the earlier Matrix code (which seems to be well used within the new Matrix as a programming language) to create something called a 'modal', basically a "tiny-ass" scenario built out of Matrix code.

> **Bugs:** *Weird. It’s some kind of Modal.*
>
> **Seq:** *Looks like old code.*
>
> **Bugs:** *It feels really familiar.*

Modals are a familiar enough concept that they have a name and their use is easily described.

> **Bugs:** *Okay. My name is Bugs. As in “Bunny.” And tech that listens. Do you know this is a Modal?*
>
> **Morpheus/Agent:** *What’s a Modal?*
>
> **Bugs:** *It’s a simulation used to evolve programs. Do you understand that you are… digital sentience?*

Running an entire Matrix-within-a-Matrix would seem to be out of scope of the computer that Neo is using, although he's certainly capable of hosting a few buildings, an NPC Trinity, some NPC policemen and some NPC Agents in a sim that's convincing enough to fool an experienced Matrix Operator for about half a minute.

---

Later in the film, General Niobe describes Zion as being stuck inside its own Matrix, although in this instance she's speaking metaphorically, not literally. **There's no indication whatsoever that the reality of Zion/Io isn't anything other than actually real.**

> Because we needed synthients and D.I. like him. Zion was stuck in the
> past. Stuck in war. **Stuck in a Matrix of its own**. They believed that
> it had to be us or them. This city was built by us and them.

Comment: Wow, searched for "Modal" word (I watched Ukrainian version with word "Module"), was directed to reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/movies/comments/rmf1h8/official_discussion_the_matrix_resurrections/hpnlohd/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3 "At the beginning Bugs hacked into a matrix within the Matrix. It think it was supposed to be a nod to all the fan theories of a matrix within a matrix that came about between the 2nd and 3rd movies."